# Re-creating build environment for Backbone.js source files (amd-app.js)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, build, amd

A new client of mine has come to me with a web site that consists of a Backbone.js app front-end (I think) and a PHP back-end. The front-end is split over multiple javascript files and directories, but in production the whole thing runs from one concatenated and minified file called amd-app.js.

I need to make some adjustments to the front-end and fix a few bugs. The previous developer was kind enough to leave the un-minified source of the entire javascript app for me, but without any build files or documentation.

How do I approach recreating a build environment for an existing Backbone.js app? Can we guess the toolchain that he probably used if the built app is called amd-app.js?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's what google brings up for your query: https://www.google.de/search?q=amd-app.js

As it appears to me, *amd* hints to some sort of [amd](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD)-style javascript dependency resolver - like [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) for instance. In fact, you could check the exploded source for hints in this direction.

Like, are there .js-files containing amd-style definitions like:

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone) {
    // sth. like this or similar
});
```

As for your question about what build environment could be used with such an app, I don't have enough information to judge about what really fits your need. I'd go for a setup using [bower](http://bower.io/) for dependency management and [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) for building my application - including minification etc.